# Comixology comic store to SD card, not internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, 4.2-jelly-bean, external-sd, sd-card

[Comixology](https://www.comixology.co.uk) insists on storing its downloaded comics on the internal storage.  This is clearly rather annoying since it is tiny compared to gigantic external SD card that is installed. The OS version is Android 4.2 Jelly Bean.

Using [ES file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop), I can see where the comics are downloaded just fine.  I could move them but that will not help as the main application would have no idea where the directory went.

Does anyone know of a way to move the existing data to the SD card and have the [Comixology](https://www.comixology.co.uk) application use the SD card?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: @beeshyams: No, I am not.

Comment: I have not tested this as all my phones end up being rooted within a week.  In case  it  helps, will upgrade to  answer status after your confirmation.    How To Install Apps Onto Your SD Card (No Root) http://m.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-apps-onto-your-SD-Card-No-Root/

Comment: Welcome. Also suggest edit update your question to show Android version, as the  answer to this varies and  to  get the correct response

Comment: I don't believe even if you follow @beeshyams method, you'll be able to have what you want.

Comment: OP, were you able to check out ? Quite forgotten about this till the above current that it may not work @SarpSTA you may be right but reasons?

Comment: @beeshyams If the application itself doesn't support the feature of choosing the directory to look for comics, it means it most probably is hard-coded. Which means where the app is installed is completely independent from where the comics are installed. OP wants to set the download directory for the **comics** (or at least that's what he asks for in the question).

Comment: @SarpSTA you have a point. Let's see if OP cares to revert

Comment: I tried. It did not work.  The application itself is installed on the SD card but the comics themselves are installed on the main (tiny) drive.